# rabbitmq refused to connect

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I just use docker to install rabbitmq, and I ran it with command:

```
docker run -d --hostname rabbitTest --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 -v /etc/rabbitmq:/etc/rabbitmq daocloud.io/library/rabbitmq:3.6.9
```

And following is the config file of rabbitmq:

```
[ { rabbit, [
    { loopback_users, ["ehoo100"] },
    { tcp_listeners, [ {"0.0.0.0", 5672} ] },
    { ssl_listeners, [ ] },
    { hipe_compile, false }
] } ]
```

I can access the web management with http://ip:15672, but when I use spring-boot to connect to it, it will cause refused connection exception.

Here are my spring-boot config:

```
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(rabbitMQProperties.getHost(),rabbitMQProperties.getPort());
        connectionFactory.setUsername(rabbitMQProperties.getUsername());
        connectionFactory.setPassword(rabbitMQProperties.getPassword());
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(rabbitMQProperties.getVirtualHost());
        connectionFactory.setPublisherConfirms(true);
        return connectionFactory;
    }
```

The port is 5672, and the exception stack trace:

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:368)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:565)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:336)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1136)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1387)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:50)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:907)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1000)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:356)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```